# How to render a view in Kohana

Tags: view, controller, kohana-3

I just started using Kohana and I'm having some trouble rendering a simple view. I created the following controller:

```
class Controller_Tracer extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {        
        $this->request->response = View::factory('tracer');
    }

}
```

Then I've created this view in application/views/tracer.php:

```
Tracer view
```

Now when I try to access the controller via http://mydomain/index.php/tracer/index it's just displaying a blank page. It seems to be finding both the controller and view since when I change the names there are errors but it's just not displaying anything.

Does anybody know what could be the issue?

Comment: What version of Kohana are you using? 3.0 or 3.1?

Comment: I suggest you to check webserver's response (via Firebug, for example). Possible its a 5xx error.

Comment: In Firebug I see a 200 OK response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kohana 3.1 you would instead use:

```
$this->response->body(View::factory('tracer'));
```

Have a quick look over the docs for [migrating from 3.0 to 3.1](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/upgrading).

Comment: Thanks! That will teach not to use Google's quick links to access the documentation page (it currently links to the 2.0 doc which then has a link to the 3.0 doc but not 3.1).

Answer (score 4):

Besides davgothic's solution, you also can use Controller_Template. Using Controller_Template make it easier to manage template & content

```
class Controller_Tracer extends Controller {

    public $template = 'yourtemplatefile'; // HTML template inside views folder

    public function before() {

        parent::before();
        $this->template->title = 'My Website';

    }

    public function action_index() {        

        $this->template->content = 'Hello World';
    }

    public function action_trace() {
        $this->template->content = View::factory('tracer');
    }
}
```

Inside views/yourtemplatefile.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : ''; ?></title>
    </head>

    <body>

       <h1><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : ''; ?></h1>

       <?php echo isset($content) ? $content : ''; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Inside views/tracer.php:

```
<p>This is tracer.</p>

<p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
```

If you try to access http://mydomain/index.php/tracer/index, you will get:

> ## My Website
>
> Hello World

If you try to access http://mydomain/index.php/tracer/trace, you will get:

> ## My Website
>
> This is tracer.
>
> Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.

Hope that helps!